# Monitor rows/sec speed that SSAS is reading data into the cube from SQL Server

Tags: ssas

I have SSAS cube and SQL Server as datasource. I was wondering if there is some screen in Sql Server Management Studio or some log file or statistic where I could find loading speed and specifically how fast was reading of data from SQL server table to the cube.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rows read/sec` performance counter displays the rate of rows read from the database objects that the cube is supported by during processing.  This can be found under the `Processing` performance counter category.  To view this counter, open a new Performance Monitor window, find the `Processing` group among the related SSAS performance counter groups and add the `Rows read/sec`, and any other counters that you're interested, in a new session.  For more details on this and other SSAS performance counters see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/performance-counters-ssas?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have opened Perf monitor but I cannot find SSAS performance counter group.

Comment: In performance monitor look for the name of the account that SSAS runs under.  If you need to find this, open SQL Server Configuration Manager by typing mmc in a search from the Windows Start button.  In Configuration Manager, go to the SQL Server Services node and look for SQL Server Analysis Services.  The account it uses will be in the Log On As column.

Comment: I have found the account but I don't know where in the Performance monitor to look, maybe some print screen would be helpful? :( Thanks!

Comment: A have found it!